# Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth does not work

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
```

```
[    4.382987] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.383014] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.383016] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.383021] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.383023] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.383029] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.663829] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
[    4.663832] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[    9.072626] xfs filesystem being remounted at /run/systemd/unit-root/var/lib/bluetooth supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    9.127087] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.127091] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.127095] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Equipment model: ar5b22

syslog

```
Apr 20 20:39:58 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Apr 20 20:39:58 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Apr 20 20:39:58 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[25096]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Apr 20 20:39:58 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[25096]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
Apr 21 11:37:02 wuhao-QTJ5 bluetoothd[1345]: Terminating
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.382987] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.383014] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.383016] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.383021] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.383023] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.383029] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.663829] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    4.663832] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
Apr 21 11:37:33 wuhao-QTJ5 NetworkManager[1035]: <info>  [1650512253.6785] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.4/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Apr 21 11:37:34 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    9.072626] xfs filesystem being remounted at /run/systemd/unit-root/var/lib/bluetooth supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 bluetoothd[1362]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 bluetoothd[1362]: Starting SDP server
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 bluetoothd[1362]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    9.127087] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    9.127091] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Apr 21 11:37:35 wuhao-QTJ5 kernel: [    9.127095] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Apr 21 11:40:09 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Apr 21 11:40:09 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Apr 21 11:40:09 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[2084]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Apr 21 11:40:09 wuhao-QTJ5 systemd[2084]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
```

Dir  /lib/firmware/

```
  ls /lib/firmware/ar*
    /lib/firmware/ar5523.bin
```

inxi -Fxxxz

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0
    Desktop: GNOME 42.0 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 42.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hasee product: QTJ5 v: 03 serial: <superuser required>
    Chassis: Quanta type: 10 v: US serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Type2 - Board Vendor Name1 model: Type2 - Board Product Name1
    v: Type2 - Board Version serial: <superuser required> UEFI-[Legacy]: Insyde
    v: BR111 date: 02/02/2015
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel 0000 bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Haswell rev: 2 cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1265 high: 1996 min/max: 800/2000 cores: 1: 1996
    2: 1451 3: 798 4: 798 5: 798 6: 1055 7: 1995 8: 1229 bogomips: 31924
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: QUANTA
    driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: eDP-1 empty: HDMI-A-1,VGA-1
    bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:0416 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M] vendor: QUANTA driver: nvidia
    v: 510.60.02 pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 4 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1347 class-ID: 0302
  Device-3: Chicony USB HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-4:3
    chip-ID: 04f2:b506 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 compositor: gnome-shell driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    display-ID: :1 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 98 s-size: 499x280mm (19.6x11.0")
    s-diag: 572mm (22.5")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 142
    size: 344x194mm (13.5x7.6") diag: 395mm (15.5") modes: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.1 compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio
    vendor: QUANTA driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0
    chip-ID: 8086:0c0c class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio vendor: QUANTA
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:8c20
    class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-27-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: QUANTA driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    port: 4000 bus-ID: 08:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Foxconn driver: ath9k v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 0f:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0034 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp15s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai type: USB driver: N/A bus-ID: 3-7:4
    chip-ID: 0489:e04e class-ID: e001
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 707.97 GiB used: 487.1 GiB (68.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Big Reservoir model: BR 240G size: 223.57 GiB
    speed: 3.0 Gb/s type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 3B0 scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS725050A7E630
    size: 465.76 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter>
    rev: B550 scheme: MBR
  ID-3: /dev/sdc model: SATA SSD size: 18.64 GiB speed: 3.0 Gb/s type: SSD
    serial: <filter> rev: M018 scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 18.63 GiB used: 10.29 GiB (55.3%) fs: xfs dev: /dev/sdc1
  ID-2: /home size: 160.28 GiB used: 77.48 GiB (48.3%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/sda2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 945.5 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0 C pch: 44.5 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 281 Uptime: 4h 56m wakeups: 1 Memory: 11.6 GiB
  used: 2.28 GiB (19.6%) Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers:
  gcc: 11.2.0 alt: 11 Packages: 1744 apt: 1735 snap: 9 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: deepin-terminal inxi: 3.3.13
```

There is this file /lib/firmware/ar3k

$ du -h /lib/firmware/ar3k

```
36K    /lib/firmware/ar3k
```

There is no ar3k directory in Ubuntu 22.04 directory. I try to create this directory, and then execute `sudo cp linux-firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu /lib/firmware/ar3k`. after restart, dmesg reports that a new file is missing：Patch file not found ar3k/ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu, and then I go to Google to find a copy. After restart, the error becomes like this

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i blue
[    4.444301] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.444340] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.444342] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.444348] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.444352] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.444357] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.285799] Bluetooth: Firmware loading err = -110, len = 448, size = 4096, count = 4470
[    8.285815] Bluetooth: Loading sysconfig file failed
[    9.639233] xfs filesystem being remounted at /run/systemd/unit-root/var/lib/bluetooth supports timestamps until 2038 (0x7fffffff)
[    9.685603] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.685607] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.685611] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I download file at :https://github.com/cernekee/linux-firmware/blob/master/ar3k/ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu

Comment: Hello! You need to add a lot more info about what you're trying to do when adding Bluetooth devices, and what error messages you get.

Comment: It's reported as a bug - please expand on the bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1967935

Comment: You need to find the firmware file `AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu`. It is possible to extract it from a Windows driver.

Comment: It has been already added to `linux-firmware`. See my answer.

Comment: I had similar initial fun with ubuntu 22.04 mate on aus pn51 but solved by just doing apt install linux-firmware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The firmware for your Bluetooth hardware isn't installed. You can install it this way. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu /lib/firmware/ar3k
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Your Bluetooth should be working.

Comment: I have the same issue, tried to make what Pilot6 said but didn`t work.
[I have installed bluez and blueman tools. In ubuntu 20.04, this solved the same problem. But now, this happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNg5t.png)

Comment: May need to do sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service && sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service after

Comment: thank you Pilot6,After I install your steps, dmesg still displays the same error as before after restarting

Comment: 443  git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
  444  sudo cp linux-firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu /lib/firmware/ar3k
  445  sudo modprobe -r btusb
  446  sudo modprobe btusb
  447  sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service && sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service

Comment: Please don't add information in comments, [edit] your question. Please add output of `ls /lib/firmware/ar3k`

Comment: Please edit YOUR question, not my answer. You should have `/lib/firmware/ar3k` directory. If not run `sudo apt  install --reinstall linux-firmware`. If there is an error with another file, then copy this file too the same way.

Comment: thank you  Pilot6,My Bluetooth device is already working

Answer (score 2):

I too HAD this problem. Then I tested 22.10 and had the same problem. Turns out starting with 22.04, Blueman added a new "feature" called "Hide unnamed devices" in the View pull-down menu. The real problem is that feature defaults to enabled. Guess what? EVERY BT device is unknown, UNTIL IT'S NOT! So they're all hidden. Not smart.

Just uncheck this box, put your BT device in pairing mode, click Search, and enjoy Bluetooth again!