# Bletooth no longer working after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 - FIXED after upgrade (firmware)

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, 21.10, 22.04

on my 2in1 Asus T300FA I can not enable bluetooth in any way after updating from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04.  Previously everithing was ok and I could install a bluetooth mouse.
Now I can't switch to on bluetooth.
I gave some command in terminal:

`rfkill`:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service;   enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-02 14:51:10 CEST; 2min 31s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 9250 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4509)
     Memory: 668.0K
        CPU: 116ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─9250 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

mag 02 14:51:10 T300FA-Ubuntu21-04 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
mag 02 14:51:10 T300FA-Ubuntu21-04 bluetoothd[9250]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
mag 02 14:51:10 T300FA-Ubuntu21-04 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
mag 02 14:51:10 T300FA-Ubuntu21-04 bluetoothd[9250]: Starting SDP server
mag 02 14:51:10 T300FA-Ubuntu21-04 bluetoothd[9250]: Bluetooth management inter>
```

So I do not know what to do.  Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

05/10/2022 The issue has been fixed with today's upgrade.  Thanks

Comment: Is it by any chance a Qualcomm WiFi/Bluetooth chipset? It's a common problem. [Link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403454/ubuntu-22-04-bluetooth-does-not-work), [link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403817/i-cant-turn-on-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts), [link 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404190/ubuntu-22-04-bluetooth-adapter-is-not-availible).

Comment: If it is atheros `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware/jammy-proposed`

Comment: More information about hardware:
luetooth:
  Device-1: IMC Networks type: USB driver: N/A bus-ID: 2-4:4
    chip-ID: 13d3:3472 class-ID: e001